# Dynamics Crm 2011 Email Draft Hyperlink

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, dynamics-crm-2011

I try to create a Hyperlink in an Email draft in Mycrosoft Dynamics Crm 2011.

My problem is that in the draft I dynamically add a link, which I get from a field of the record. The link is added and everything is working fine, but I need to add the link and hide the url, so I need to somehow set the InnerHtml from the link. I don't want to show the url-content. Is that somehow possible? Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamicly creating email, for adding url choose option 'Insert Hyperlink'.
Just enter 'Text to display', and for Url choose appropriate Url from a field of the record.

Hope it helps.

[image: Example]